# tf.keras.Model training accuracy jumps after running Model.evaluate() during training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm training a TensorFlow Keras `Model` using `Model.fit()`. I'm also using callbacks to log my training accuracy metrics after every batch using TensorFlow's `on_train_batch_end()` syntax. In addition, I'm using another callback to run `Model.evaluate()` every 1,000 batches to compute validation set accuracy and update the `logs` dict passed around the callbacks during `Model.fit()`.

Looking at the logged metrics vs. batch number shows very perplexing results. After the `Model.evaluate()` run, the training accuracy experiences a significant 'jolt', initially triggering a rapid increase in the logged training accuracy and subsequently triggering a significant drop training accuracy followed by a slower recovery (see attached images).

My guess is that it's something to do with the [Model.evaluate()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1242-L1394)'s call to `reset_metrics()`, which loops through and calls the [reset_states()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L241) method on each metric. I can't work out what `reset_states()` is doing and if this is relevant to the behaviour I'm observing. It seems to relate to the [Mean](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L445) parent class of `CategoricalAccuracy`. I haven't been able to find anything helpful in the TensorFlow docs yet.

Are the metrics shown during `Model.fit()` actually some form of moving averages rather than the batch-wise metric? In that case, the `reset_states()` method would be resetting the moving average, possibly producing the jolting behaviour.

Can anyone with a better grasp of TensorFlow's inner workings help?

[image: Jolting accuracy.]

[image: Jolting accuracy (zoomed in).]

Comment: Have you checked already whether your intermediate evaluation maybe results in the undesired accumulation of losses or gradients which might then (possibly) be applied during the first weight update after evaluation?

Comment: Thanks @DanielB. I am certainly worried that the call to `Model.evaluate()` is silently training on my validation data. That is my other hypothesis. If true, however, I would expect higher accuracies over the validation set than I am observing. Also, `Model.evaluate()` is supposed to put the network in 'test mode', which I would _hope_ means not gradients are computed. Thoughts welcomed.